# Post a value to a PHP file and reload HTML page when the value has been processed?

Tags: php, html, ajax, post

I am working on an application that displays a linechart from database records.
The user views the graphic in a html page and can change the parameters to view the chart he is interested in by selecting them from a select box.
Behind the html page there is php page that does the query to the database and converts the result into json format to be used for the graphic in the html page.

Right now I am trying to post the values from the select box (with the parameters the user selected) into the php page, but I don't want to see the php afterward, instead I want the html page to be refreshed to show the new graphic with the selected values.

To post the values to php I am using something like this:

```
<form action="index.php" target="_blank" method="post">
 <select name="Tasel" onchange="this.form.submit()">
 <option value="3">Tuloslaskelma</option>
 <option value="2">Tasevastattava</option>
 <option value="1">Tasevastaava</option>   
 </select>
```

It posts the values ok, but now I don't know how to reload the html with the new graphic at the same time. I would appreciate some suggestions on what is the best way to go here. I have read several suggestions about using Ajax, but haven't really found the way to make it work. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your code should already do what you ask. When you change the select your form will post to index.php. If index.php also hosts your form, you will see your form right after the post again.

Comment: That's the thing. I use the POST method in the html page (the one that displays the chart) and I want it to pass the values to index.php and then reload. When the change is made on the select, the values are posted and the index.php is loaded, but what I need is to load the updated HTML page with the new graphic, not the php.

Comment: Easiest fix is what @user543732 answered. Just add a `header('Location:  <url of your form>');` to the bottom of your index.php. Using referer is a bit dodgy though, because its not 100% sure that it'll be filled (its something the browser sends)

Comment: Yes, the header('Location: <url of your form>'); works to load the html page but it does not take the values of the post. The html loads, but with no changes.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **redirect-after-post** pattern is a cleaner solution to the problem you face.

A more advanced description can be found [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post).

Another point is that you need to take care about the *response headers* sent by your *webserver* alongside the *image response*. If there is something like caching involved it might cause the old picture to be displayed.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do... the article is quite good, just now I just have to figure out how to code it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn a bit more about JavaScript (or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) if you prefer) if you want to use Ajax.

Otherwise, you can simply put a redirect after the form process (in index.php) is complete.

`index.php`

```
<?php

// Form processor here

// Make sure nothing is outputted to the browser

header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
exit();
```

Comment: The header('Location: <url of your form>'); works to load the html, but when it loads there are not changes on it. Apparently it does not carry the values posted from the php, and does not update the graphic.

Comment: Maybe we read the question wrong. The main page, where the `<form...>` located, is it actually a pure HTML file? If it is, then no other option but to use Ajax.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't manage to explain it properly. The php page obtains the records from the database and converts the whole array to json format. Then the main page (html, where the form is located) gets that value and displays the graphic. The user only needs to see and interact with the html page, which needs to be updated according to the user selected parameters. The php page makes the query for the graphic based on the parameters the html form posts.